# scipy for ABAQUS on 64 bit Windows system

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a Python script, which is used in ABAQUS and calls numpy and scipy. I switched from a 32-bit Windows machine to a 64-bit machine. I have problems installing scipy for ABAQUS 6.13.1 on my new 64-bit system. Could anybody give me some tips on how to get scipy running for ABAQUS and provide me with the compatible version of scipy?

Regards.

Comment: You should ask Dassault for support. Very hard for us to know details about ABAQUS which is pretty niche for programmers. How do we know which version of Python you are using? Or whether you need 32 or 64 bit Python. At the very least you could add some details here. But really this is a question you should ask of the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Download and Install a 64 bit version of Anaconda. https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Using Conda, downgrade the version of SciPy to be compatible with the Abaqus version of NumPy.
In Abaqus/CAE python shell, check version of NumPy:

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
```

In a windows command window type:

```
conda install scipy numpy=1.6
```

Copy the scipy directory from the Anaconda site-packages directory into the Abaqus.  e.g.

From:

> C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\scipy

To:

> C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\6.14-1\tools\SMApy\python2.7\Lib\site-packages\scipy

Maybe not all SciPy functions will work (I think a pip install will correctly link all dependencies but I have not tried this method) but the SciPy spline curve fitting functions certainly worked well!

Comment: Yeah I got SciPy to install but couldnt get `from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull` to work. When you say pip install will correct dependencies how would I go about this?

Comment: My version of SciPy is 0.11.0.   Do this to find your version:
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version__
Unfortunately ConvexHull requires 0.12.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the compiled 64 bit version hosted here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: do you have the executable saved by any chance? I think the one on the website is broken! not working.

Answer (score -1):

You can know which version of Python runs on your Abaqus by running the following in your command prompt in the bottom panel of Abaqus:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
```

[Installing the corresponding version of Python and SciPy](https://abaquslearner.wordpress.com/2014/12/18/numpy-and-scipy-in-abaqus/) in the Abaqus folder will help